# Define Path for swagger doc

Tags: api-platform.com

My **API** route ist **/api/v1**. As I use JWT and FOSUserBundle I would like to have the **swagger doc under /api-doc/v1**. Has anyone an idea how to set a different route for the doc?

Thanks & best

Answer (score 0):

routing.yml

```
NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing/swaggerui.xml"
    prefix:   /api-doc
```

Doc:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/nelmio-api-doc